# Recursively remove key and value inside array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, recursion

I have a plist file which contains array of dictionaries [image]

How can I traverse through this and remove all keys and value with key fQty? I need to remove fQty so that I can compare the dictionary to a new dictionary disregarding the fQty field.

Comment: @Wain, I have created the recursive function to traverse the array. But I haven't removed the key fQty.

Comment: You should show your existing code and tell us what it does wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### (assume your pilst file named: data.plist)

```
- (void) deal:(id)item
{
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        for (id key in item) {
            id it = [item objectForKey:key];
            if ([it isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [it isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                [self deal:it];
            }
        }
        if ([item objectForKey:@"fQty"]!=nil) {
            [item setObject:@"0" forKey:@"fQty"];
        }
    }
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (id it in item) {
            if ([it isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [it isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                [self deal:it];
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    NSError** error = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSArray *dma = (NSMutableArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                             propertyListWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"XD" ofType:@"plist"]]
                                            options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                             format:&format error:error];

    [self deal:dma];
}
```

---

now the myArray is what you want.

EDIT: you want set the value of key @"fQty" to 0,

change the line in for loop to [item setObject:@"0" forKey:@"fQty"], that's it.

**EDIT AGAIN:
solve the problem with recursive way.**

Comment: sorry but I didn't mean to remove the object. I want the key to be removed.

Comment: thank you so much! :) This only caters to one dimensional array. Kindly check the image that I've attached. There are fQty keys also inside another array :)

Comment: edited again. recursive see (1)array: deal with this array (2)dictionary: edit the value of the key.

Maybe Joshua's solution is also work, but I never test it, you can try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little rough but maybe you can use something like this:

```
-(BOOL)isObjectAdictionary:(id)object{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]||[object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

 -(BOOL)isObjectAnArray:(id)object{
      if([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]||[object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
         return YES;
      }
     return NO;
   }


-(id)loop:(id)object removeObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key{

if([self isObjectAdictionary:object]){
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:object];
    if([[mutableObject allKeys]containsObject:key]){
        [mutableObject removeObjectForKey:key];
        object = mutableObject;
        return object;
    }

}

if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]){


    if([self isObjectAdictionary:object]){
        NSMutableDictionary *objects_copy = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:object];
        for(NSString *objects_key in object){

            id tempObject = [object valueForKey:objects_key];
            tempObject = [self loop:tempObject removeObjectWithKey:key];
            [objects_copy setObject:tempObject forKey:objects_key];
        }
        object =(id)objects_copy;
    }
    else if([self isObjectAnArray:object]){//an array
        NSMutableArray *objects_copy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:object];
        for(int i = 0;i<[object count];i++){
            id tempObject = [object objectAtIndex:i];
           tempObject = [self loop:tempObject removeObjectWithKey:key];
            [objects_copy replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tempObject];
        }
        object = (id)objects_copy;
    }

}
 return object;
}
```

you can use like this:`[self loop:yourArray removeObjectWithKey:@"fQty"]);`

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I want to remove the key fQty instead of removing the object with key fQty.

Comment: do you want to replace the key with a different key? because a dictionary can't have an object without a key.. also in your question it says you want to remove the key and value

Comment: Hi Joshua, I read other posts and have come to know that key cannot be removed. In this case, I will just set the value of fQty to 0. I need to do this because I need to compare the existing list of "ordered items" in the plist file to the "new orders" to be made by the customer. So that if the order is just the same, I will not insert a new item. I will increase the quantity instead.